# Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock Difference Result not working

Tags: python, difference

Everything is fine, but the Difference variable. I have tried searching for an answer but it doesn't work and I need help with it.

```
import random



selection = {0 : "Rock", 1 : "Paper", 2 : "Scissors", 3 : "Lizard", 4 : "Spock"}


Playerwins = 0
Computerwins = 0


def RPSLS():

definition RPSLS()

    global Playerwins, Computerwins

    Player = random.randrange(5)
    Computer = random.randrange(5)

    print "Player chooses", selection[Player]
    print "Computer chooses", selection[Computer]

    Difference = (Player - Computer) % 5



    if Difference == 0:
        print "Player and Computer tie!"
    elif Difference <= 2:
        Playerwins += 1
        print "Player Wins!"
    else:
        Computerwins += 1
        print "Computer Wins!"

    print "Player Wins:", Playerwins
    print "Computer Wins:", Computerwins
    print "\n"

def main():
    while Computerwins or Playerwins != 10:

        raw_input("\nPress the enter key to start a game.")
        print "\n"
        RPSLS()
        if Computerwins or Playerwins == 10:
            if Computerwins == 10:
                print "Sorry you lost, Computer wins!"
                break
            elif Playerwins == 10:
                print "Congratulations you won!"
                break
main()

# Allowing the user to exit the program

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: What do you mean *Everything is fine, but the Difference variable* . You would need to explain how is it *not fine* .

Comment: How is it not fine? What is the issue?

Comment: This part of the code with Difference = (Player - Computer) % 5 seems to work for most people, but when I tried implanting it didn't work

Comment: When you run it, you get a answer if the player or computer won but not every time it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is wrong, for correct answers the correct order is -

```
selection = {0 : "Rock", 1 : "Spock", 2 : "Paper", 3 : "Lizard", 4 : "Scissors"}
```

---

Also, other issues in your code -

```
while Computerwins or Playerwins != 10:
```

This is wrong, this is not how you check if either of the values have reached 10, it would check if `Computerwins` is not 0 or empty string/empty list, etc (in which case it means True) or playerwins has not reached 10 , so the only condition this while loop exits would be when computerwins is 0 and playerwins has reached 10. It should be -

```
 while Computerwins != 10 or Playerwins != 10:
```

Similar issue with the if condition -

```
 if Computerwins or Playerwins == 10:
```

It should be -

```
if Computerwins == 10 or Playerwins == 10:
```

Currently that part of code correctly works only because of the `if..elif` block inside the above mentioned `if` , but after fixing the while loop, the complete `if` part can be moved outside the while statement like -

```
def main():
    while Computerwins != 10 or Playerwins != 10:
        raw_input("\nPress the enter key to start a game.")
        print "\n"
        RPSLS()

    if Computerwins == 10:
        print "Sorry you lost, Computer wins!"
    elif Playerwins == 10:
        print "Congratulations you won!"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Sorry about not explaining the issues.